# How to select columns with the same pattern on Excel Power Query

Tags: excel, powerquery, m

I have multiple columns that its names ends with something like " - Hello" and " - Goodbye". So i tried using `Table.SelectColumns` with some kind of a regular expression to select all columns with this pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
= Table.SelectColumns(Source, List.Select(Table.ColumnNames(Source),
                      each Text.EndsWith(_," - Goodbye") or Text.EndsWith(_," - Hello")))
```

Comment: So many complex solutions for this requirement on this site and others - yours is by far the most elegant and easy to implement. Thanks Aleksei!